# Is there a tool for testing the performance of reading and compression of a file format?

Tags: performance-testing, files

I am comparing different file formats for understanding which has the best performance for my case. I use these data formats for storing data-sets created from different analytical techniques. I wrote some Python scripts for analyzing the compression ratio now I am trying to implement something for measuring the access time I know that for many indicators I will have only relative value but I would like to know if there is a tool that allows me to test file formats and helping me in choosing the best one for my application.

Comment: Any feedback on how to improve the question is appreciated.

Comment: The word "performance" is not applicable to file formats. Change the title to sth like "performance of reading files of different formats".

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that you're looking for a [microbenchmark](https://www.codeblueprint.co.uk/2016/10/08/what-is-microbenchmark.html) library for your programming language.

This "microbenchmark" approach allows testing single functions with multiple threads/iterations/input data and reports the trends. So just look for "microbenchmark" libraries/packages for your programming language and you should be able to use the approach for the comparison.

If you don't have access to the source code of the application you can go for "macrobenchmark", to wit testing the whole application with different file formats and comparing the output. Depending on the application nature you can use a [suitable load testing tool](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview) which provides the same performance metrics which you could compare. Check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use/) article for example load testing tool assessment/selection criteria.